# How do i use php curl instead of header('Location:) to return a token?

Tags: curl, oauth-2.0, token, exact-online

I have an API link from my site to Exact Online and this works. The first step in authorisation is to return the token from the Exact Online site. The code uses header() to do this as shown in my code below. However, the header() redirect on my site (to return the token) does not work when I redirect to my site from another site (i.e. when I try to get a different website to access the API query through my website, as if white labelling the query). I suspect that if I replace the header() on my website with a CURL request, this might work, but so far I have not been able to do so - could someone please help me with this?

This is the code which works:

```
if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {
// If there is no token, this returns the token with the 'code' parameter
$url = "https://start.exactonline.co.uk/api/oauth2/auth";
$params = array(
    "response_type" => "code",
    "client_id" => $clientId,
    "redirect_uri" => $redirectUri
    );
$request_to = $url . '?' . http_build_query($params);
header("Location: " . $request_to);
die('Redirect');
}
```

I tried this and it was not successful:

```
$curlOpt = array();
$curlOpt[CURLOPT_URL] = 'https://start.exactonline.co.uk/api/oauth2/auth?client_id=XXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=ZZZZZZZZ';
$curlOpt[CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER] = FALSE;
$curlOpt[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = FALSE;
$curlOpt[CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION] = TRUE;
$curlOpt[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = array(
    'response_type' => 'code');
$curlHandle = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curlHandle, $curlOpt);
curl_exec($curlHandle);
```

I suspect that my CURL request is not correct, but I don't know how to fix it and any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The call to the auth-endpoint is always a regular GET (as in your first example). This will show the loginpage. Doesn't matter from which site you're coming.

Comment: Thanks - I'll see if Exact permits the client credentials grant type so that I can post the credentials and get an auth token without the need for a user login.